# Mysql - return sum of total person comments with the person query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%".$data."%'";
```

Assuming I have another table named `comments`, and in this table I have `person_id` field, how I can return the total number (SUM) of comments of each user **with** the data from the query above?

Comment: Join the 2 tables, and add the `SUM `to your `SELECT`

Comment: Hopefully this isn't a real application.... This is open to SQL injection attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final working query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,COUNT(comments.id) FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.people_id = p.id
 WHERE p.name LIKE '%".$data."%'";
```

Answer (score -2):

Im new with this but i think i might have an idea to help you

I would do something like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%".$data."%'";
while($rowdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql ))
{
   //Every person's id 

   $person_id = $rowdata ['person_id'];
   $sqlcomments = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE person_id = '.$person_id.'";

   //Total comments for each person
   $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($sqlcomments );
}
```

Hope it helps